# Changing the theme color of Ant Design in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, themes, next.js, antd, server-side-rendering

I'm making a nextjs website which uses ant design as the UI framework. I have to make a feature that the primary color would change depends on different suitations.

I can make it work on browser, but not in server side. Does anyone have any idea of making it work on server side?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting on the server side?

Comment: eg: primary color could be change while rendering in server side

Comment: Give more info regarding the question, sample code, screenshots

Comment: I guess you have to save the user preference in the cookie and read it on the server-side to render the right theme.